# How to move move a rectangle in JFrame using KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I'm trying to get a rectangle in my JFrame to move when I press a given key on the keyboard, but I'm seemingly having a hard time doing that. Here's my code:

```
package TestPackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Mainframe extends JComponent implements KeyListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int x = 350;
    int y = 250;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Mainframe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize (800, 600);
        frame.setFocusable (true);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground (Color.WHITE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new Mainframe());
        frame.addKeyListener (new Mainframe());
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.setColor (Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillRect (x, y, 100, 100);
    }

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            x++;
            repaint();
        }
        else if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            y++;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent event) {}
    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent event) {}
}
```

I'm sure it's a problem with my KeyListener, as everything else works perfectly. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're creating two instances of `MainFrame`, one you add to the frame and one you use as the `JFrame`'s `KeyListener`, this means that any modifications the `KeyListener` instance makes to the `x/y` values, won't be seen by the instance on the UI
2. Don't use `KeyListener`, it has too many focus related issues, use the Key Bindings API which was designed to overcome these issues.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
3. Don't override `paint` (and especially if you're not going to call `super.paint`), instead, you should override the `paintComponent` method (and call `super.paintComponent`). See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
4. Make sure you are creating and modifying the UI only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Mainframe extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int x = 350;
    int y = 250;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mainframe");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setFocusable(true);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new Mainframe());
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Mainframe() {
        bindKeyWith("y.up", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), new VerticalAction(-1));
        bindKeyWith("y.down", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), new VerticalAction(1));
        bindKeyWith("x.left", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), new HorizontalAction(-1));
        bindKeyWith("x.right", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), new HorizontalAction(1));
    }

    protected void bindKeyWith(String name, KeyStroke keyStroke, Action action) {
        InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        im.put(keyStroke, name);
        am.put(name, action);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
    }

    public abstract class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private int delta;

        public MoveAction(int delta) {
            this.delta = delta;
        }

        public int getDelta() {
            return delta;
        }

        protected abstract void applyDelta();

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            applyDelta();
        }

    }

    public class VerticalAction extends MoveAction {

        public VerticalAction(int delta) {
            super(delta);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyDelta() {
            int delta = getDelta();
            y += delta;
            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
            } else if (y + 100 > getHeight()) {
                y = getHeight() - 100;
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }
    public class HorizontalAction extends MoveAction {

        public HorizontalAction(int delta) {
            super(delta);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyDelta() {
            int delta = getDelta();
            x += delta;
            if (x < 0) {
                x = 0;
            } else if (x + 100 > getWidth()) {
                x = getWidth() - 100;
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code and it worked! I shall study this code and learn from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

make your main like this and it will work

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Mainframe");
        JComponent test = new Mainframe();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize (800, 600);
        frame.setFocusable (true);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground (Color.WHITE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (test);
        frame.addKeyListener ((KeyListener) test);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
```